# Anchoring one text box relative to another text box that expands with text

Tags: adobe-indesign

I am doing a merge in InDesign to create datasheets for products.  The problem is that the quantity of text in each field varies.  I have the text box setup to expand down to fit the text.  With manual spacing, if the field has to expand, it overlays the next field. The question is, how can I anchor the next merge field relative to the previous expanded text box? So in the attached picture, how can I get "Formulation" to move relative to "Description"?
 [image]

Comment: have you tried using one text frame for all the info? rather than having multiple text frames? I think that will work, also using paragraph styles to control the spacings.

Comment: I didn't think of that because I assumed that the merge fields would require their own box.  Will try.  THanks!

Comment: Great! Glad that it helped!